# Excel file is converting into a Google Docs file instead of a Spreadsheet file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

This is strange as the code works in one of my projects, but when I copy it to a new project, the excel file is converting into a docs file.

Below is the code I am using:

```
    function Conve() 
    {  
    var fileID="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    var filename = "XTRA.xlsx"
    var folderID = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
    var XLFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileID)
    var xBlob = XLFile.getBlob()
    var newFile = {
    title : "GSFILE",
    key : fileID,
    parents: [{"id": folderID}]// destination folder ID
    }        
    file = Drive.Files.insert(newFile, xBlob, {convert: true});
    }
```

Comment: The comment `// destination folder ID` is inside of your object

Comment: Can I ask you about your goal? You want to convert Microsoft Excel file to Google Spreadsheet. Or you want to convert Google Spreadsheet to Microsoft Excel file. Which do you want to achieve? In your question, you say `the excel file is converting into a docs file.`. But in your script, although `var XLFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileID)` is used, it seems that the error doesn't occur. This means that `fileID` is the ID of Google Spreadsheet. So I asked about your goal.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function Conve() {  
  var fileID="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  var filename = "XTRA.xlsx"
  var folderID = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
  var XLFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileID)
  var xBlob = XLFile.getBlob()
  var newFile={title:"GSFILE",key:fileID,parents:[{"id": folderID}]};        
  Drive.Files.insert(newFile, xBlob, {convert: true});
}
```